# Iterative / Recursion

Tags: c++, string, recursion, permutation

I have written the code for how to find the permutations for a given string using a for loop. I followed my professor's pseudocode, but am not sure how to convert it so that it is recursive. (no for, goto, while, STL algorithms).

```
void perms(string prefix, string rest)
{
    //  Followed Format of Pseudocode that Professor gave us
    //  If nothing remains in the rest string cout what we have for prefix
    if (rest == "")
    {
        cout << prefix << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < rest.length(); i++)
        {
            string prefix2 = prefix + rest[i];
            string rest2 = rest.substr(0, i) + rest.substr(i + 1);
            perms(prefix2, rest2);
        }
    }
}
```

The code works well, just need help with turning it to recursion.

Comment: uh? It already looks recursive to me.

Comment: This is still a recursive solution, as you are calling printPermutations inside of printpermutations. Are you looking for a recursive solution that doesn't use a for loop? You have a recursive step and a base case here, basically the two things you need to identify if its recursive

Comment: We aren't allowed to use any sorts of loops, we are only allowed if statements :(     I wrote it using a for loop, because I wasn't sure how to go about it only using if statements.

Comment: Could you also provide us with an example input and desired output?

Comment: Will do ! @plum0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To hoist the loop into the recursion, you have to turn the iteration variable `i` into a parameter:

Step 1:

```
void printPermutations(string prefix, string rest, int i = 0)
```

Step 2:

```
void printPermutations(string prefix, string rest, int i = 0)
{
    //  Followed Format of Pseudocode that Professor gave us
    //  If nothing remains in the rest string cout what we have for prefix
    if (rest == "")
    {
        cout << prefix << endl;
    }
    else if (i < rest.length())
    {
       // original loop body
       string prefix2 = prefix + rest[i];
       string rest2 = rest.substr(0, i) + rest.substr(i + 1);

       // true original recursion with different prefix and tail.
       printPermutations(prefix2, rest2);

       // loop continuation via tail recursion: original prefix, next i.
       printPermutations(prefix, rest, i + 1);
    }
}
```

It's almost mechanical transformation. Firstly, the initialization of `i` to `0` has moved into the argument list where we do that via defaulting (we could also have callers explicitly pass zero, when necessary).  The `for` loop header of the loop has been gutted, replaced just with the loop guard condition, which is transformed to an `if` conditional.  And then the continuation of the loop is done just by a tail call where we pass `i + 1`, which becomes the next value of `i`.

It might help to imagine this intermediate version, which is still iterative:

```
void printPermutations(string prefix, string rest)
{
    int i = 0;

topOfFunction:

    //  Followed Format of Pseudocode that Professor gave us
    //  If nothing remains in the rest string cout what we have for prefix
    if (rest == "")
    {
        cout << prefix << endl;
    }
    else if (i < rest.length())
    {
       // original loop body
       string prefix2 = prefix + rest[i];
       string rest2 = rest.substr(0, i) + rest.substr(i + 1);

       // true original recursion with different prefix and tail.
       printPermutations(prefix2, rest2);

       // loop continuation via tail recursion: original prefix, next i.
       i = i + 1;
       goto topOfFunction;
    }
}
```

Note that though the `rest == ""` check is included in the loop, we know that stays false because we never modify `rest`.

Comment: Thanks for the help @Kaz!

Answer (score 0):

Every loop can be turned into recursion:

```
void test() {
    int functionVar = 10;
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i=0, int j=2; i<10; i = i - 1, j = j + 2) {
       sum = sum + someFun(i, functionVar);
    }
    // Do something with sum
    cout << sum << endl;
}
```

Can easily be rewritten like this:

```
int forReplacement(int i, int j, int sum, functionVar) {
    if (i < 2) {
      return forReplacement(i - 1, j + 2, sum + someFun(i, functionVar), functionVar);
    }
    return sum;
}

void test() {
    int functionVar = 10;
    int sum = forReplacemenrt(0, 0, 0, functionVar);
    // Do something with sum
    cout << sum << endl;
}
```

You could make `forReplacement` a lambda and point reference it in it's closure to be able to recur and then `functionVar` and `sum` could be closure variables.